# Server-side vs client-side write speeds

Tags: performance

How do server-side and client-side write speeds differ when writing data to SharePoint? What things make client-side write speeds slower than server-side write speeds? Can we write this as a following "function"

**sudo code:**

```
[client-side write speed] = [Server-side write speed using Microsoft.SharePoint.dll] - [time of data travelling over the Network] - [time of serializing / de-serializing the data to be sent over the network] - [extra time required for batch operations] - [extra overhead required by using the client-side API??]
```

and could we get some reasonable estimate of the differences in performance?